Graded modules that are sum of their finite dimensional submodules.
Let $A$ and $B$ be $\mathbb{N}$-graded $k$-algebras such that $dim_k A_i < \infty$ and $dim_k B_i < \infty$ for all $i$. Let $\phi : A \rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism of graded $k$-algebras. Let $N$ be a graded right $A$-modules  and  $N,Ker \phi , Coker \phi$ are the sum of their finite dimensional submodules(or direct limit of their finite dimensional submodules), how to prove that $N \otimes _A B$ is the sum of its finite dimensional submodules(or direct limit of its finite dimensional submodules)?
My idea is that $N$ can be written as $N= \sum N_l$, where $N_l$ is finite dimensional,and since tensor can commutate with sum(direct limit) , $N \otimes _A B$ can be written as $\sum (N_l \otimes _A B)$. But I don't know whether $(N_l \otimes _A B)$ is finite dimensional.
It is a part of $Propositon 1.1$ of Holdaway and Smith's paper "Corrigendum to “An equivalence of categories for graded modules over monomial algebras and path algebras
of quivers". But the proof of it uses a claim "Fdim =Tors in the case". I want a direct proof about Fdim .
